# MapReduce code cleaning staging area error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to mapreduce. I am running a mapreduce program. It's compiling fine and jar file is also created without any error but when I run the final Hadoop command it shows the following error and stops.

This is the complete log:

```
    [u@h(IPC2-Gold) w]$ hadoop jar join.jar Runner -Dmapred.job.queue.name=score2 /axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/inp/file1.txt /axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/inp/file2.txt /axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/asd
14/06/19 21:28:44 INFO fs.JobTrackerWatcher: Current running JobTracker is: lgpbd1010.gso.aexp.com/10.22.45.20:9001
14/06/19 21:28:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area maprfs:/var/mapr/cluster/mapred/jobTracker/staging/rdwiv5/.staging/job_201405310436_72947
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory /axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/inp/file2.txt already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:926)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:885)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:566)
        at Runner.run(Runner.java:55)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at Runner.main(Runner.java:64)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Comment: fix up format in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have three arguments (two input files and one output dir). I think what is happening is the program only expecting two, one for input and one for output. If you want all files in a directory as the input, just use the directory as the input like

```
/axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/inp
```

Hadoop will grab all the files from that directory. What's probably happening currently is that hadoop is taking your second argument (which is another file in same directory) as the output directory, that's why you're getting the exception

Note: Check you directories and see if a

```
/axp/rim/score2/dev/cmc_score/rishabh/inp/file1.txt
```

*directory* exists. It's possible you accidentily ran a program with the path as the output, and `file1.txt` *directory* (not file) was created also. Then when you ran again trying to use the same arguments you get this exception because the directory already exists, possibly for the same reason discussed above (the program is expecting two args)

Comment: i did use simply "inp" instead of specifying file1.txt and it removed my previous error(directory named file1.txt was not the problem) but a new error has come inplace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330086/mapreduce-code-generating-array-out-of-bounds-exception

Comment: Also I was just looking at your other question. Please post the code for your mapper class (in that post). I'll look at it. Can't tell without code.